# Change class into dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to refactor a class into a dataclass, here is what I have:

```
class Tenant:
   def __init__(self, tenant: dict, api_client: str) -> None:
      self.name = tenant["name"]
      self.tenant_id= tenant["id"]
      self.subdomain = tenant["subdomain"]
      self.api_client= api_client
```

What would be the same class as a dataclass?
I tried with something like that, but I don't know how to separate this dict into name, tenant_id and subdomain:

```
@dataclass
class Tenant:
   tenant: dict
   api_client: str
```

Comment: IMO this should be a factory method named something like `from_dict`.  The "normal" constructor should take `name`/`id`/`subdomain`/`api_client` as individual args.

Comment: Define "the same". Your original class holds 4 attributes, but accepts only two arguments, and constructs itself from those those arguments. So the question is, where to put this destructuring/construction logic. It hardly makes sense to override the dataclass' `__init__`, since that's most of the benefit a `dataclass` provides you. — So, again, in what way should they be "the same" and where is it okay for them to differ?

Comment: Redesign your class - don't accept dict and convert it to instance attributes unless you have a reason to! If you really need that, be very explicit about that and use the helper function suggested below.

Comment: "I want to refactor a class into a dataclass" - don't bother. What dataclasses give you is not what you want.

Answer (score 7):

I would add a class method to the data class to extract the necessary values from a `dict`.

```
@dataclass
class Tenant:
    name: str
    tenant_id: int
    subdomain: str
    api_client: str

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, tenant: dict, api_client: str):
        return cls(tenant["name"],
                   tenant["id"],
                   tenant["subdomain"],
                   api_client)


t1 = Tenant("alice", 5, "bar", "client")
t2 = Tenant.from_dict({"name": "bob", "id": 6, "subdomain": "foo"},
                      "client")
```

I would take the same approach even if `Tenant` were *not* a dataclass. An instance of `Tenant` is only interested in the values to assign to its attributes, not how those values are packaged prior to the instance being created.

---

If you must preserve the existing API for `Tenant`, you'll need to use an `InitVar` and the `__post_init__` method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field


@dataclass
class Tenant:
    tenant: InitVar[dict]
    name: str = field(init=False)
    tenant_id: int = field(init=False)
    subdomain: str = field(init=False)
    api_client: str

    # Approximate __init__ method generated
    # def __init__(self, tenant, api_client):
    #     self.api_client = api_client
    #     self.__post_init__(tenant)

    def __post_init__(self, tenant):
        self.name = tenant["name"]
        self.tenant_id = tenant["id"]
        self.subdomain = tenant["subdomain"]

t = Tenant({"name": "bob", "id": 6, "subdomain": "foo"},
           "client")
```

`tenant`, as an `InitVar`, is passed to `__init__` and `__post_init__`, but will not be used as an attribute for the other autogenerated methods. `name`, `tenant_id`, and `subdomain` will not be accepted as arguments to `__init__`, but will be used by the other autogenerated methods. You, however, are responsible for ensuring they are set correctly in `__post_init__`.

---

A possible hybrid approach to define a "private" class, and make the name `Tenant` refer to the class method.

```
def _from_dict(cls, tenant, api_client):
    return cls(tenant["name"],
               tenant["id"],
               tenant["subdomain"],
               api_client)

# Using make_dataclass just to make the class name
# 'Tenant' instead of '_Tenant'. You can use an
# ordinary class statement and patch _Teant.__name__
# instead.
_Tenant = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
      'Tenant',
      [('name', str),
       ('tenant_id', int),
       ('subdomain', str),
       ('api_client', str)],
      namespace={'from_dict': classmethod(_from_dict)}
     )

Tenant = _Tenant.from_dict
```

Comment: But I need Tenant to accept only 2 arguments and here it demands to have 4

Comment: the `def __post_init__(self):` construct would work...

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner suggested, the idea of implementing a `.from_dict` method is definely pythonic and readable too, so i'm going to implement it in this code too.

Since the OP wants that the Class must have 2 arguments I would suggest to use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
 collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, rename=False, defaults=None, module=None)¶
```

> Returns a new tuple subclass named typename. The new subclass is used to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable

*WARNING*: I haven't tested the code yet

```
TenantnoAPI = namedtuple("Tenant_noAPI","name tenant_id subdomain")

@dataclass
class Tenant:
    tenantnoapi:TenantnoAPI
    api_client: str

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, tenant: dict, api_client: str):
        return cls(TenantnoAPI(tenant["name"],
                                tenant["id"],
                                tenant["subdomain"]),
                   api_client)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wholly concur with ***@chepner*** about using something along the lines of a `from_dict` constructor class method; at least to me, that aligns with Python best practices in general.

Another option, if (for whatever reason) you didn't want to model your data with `dataclasses`, you could instead use a dot-access dict, such as one provided by my helper library [`dotwiz`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/). This can be installed with `pip install dotwiz`, and is a relatively lightweight option that one could consider.

As a specific example:

```py
from dotwiz import DotWiz


class Tenant(DotWiz):

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, tenant: dict, api_client: str) -> 'Tenant':
        return cls(tenant_id=tenant.pop('id'), **tenant, api_client=api_client)


t = Tenant.from_dict({"name": "bob", "id": 6, "subdomain": "foo"}, "client")
print(t)  # ✫(tenant_id=6, name='bob', subdomain='foo', api_client='client')

assert t.name == 'bob'
assert t.tenant_id == 6
```

In case you want type checking, and field auto-completion:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from dotwiz import DotWiz


if TYPE_CHECKING:

    class Tenant(DotWiz):
        name: str
        id: int
        subdomain: str
        api_client: str


# noinspection PyTypeChecker
def create_tenant(tenant: dict, api_client: str) -> 'Tenant':
    tenant['api_client'] = api_client
    return DotWiz(tenant)


t = create_tenant({"name": "bob", "id": 6, "subdomain": "foo"}, "client")
```

> *Full disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintainer of this library.